# Can you pass Activity to another app through IPC/AIDL?

Tags: android, aidl

I understand that through AIDL inter-app communication is possible in Android. You can pass primitives and custom objects that implement Parcelable interface. But, can App A pass it's activity reference to App B as a Parameter to an AIDL API (for example void foo(Activity reference)). And then app B use the reference? Will it be pass by value or reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you pass Activity to another app through IPC/AIDL?

No.